# The number of characters in each unicode block

Tags: unicode

Does anyone know any reference showing the number of characters in each Unicode block? (in newer version such as 5.x.x or 6.0.0)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt contains the data you are interested in.

http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.0.0/ucd/ReadMe.txt contains some instructions and refers to http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/ for interpreting the data. In that document you should read http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#UnicodeData.txt.

Answer (score 2):

### *unichars*

Does this answer your question:

```
% unichars '\p{InCyrillic}' | wc -l
     256    
% unichars '\p{InEthiopic}' | wc -l
     356
% unichars '\p{InLatin1}' | wc -l
 128
% unichars '\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}' | wc -l
```

To include the 16 astral planes, add `-a`:
     112
    % unichars -a '\p{InAncientGreekNumbers}' | wc -l
      75

If you want unassigned or Han or Hangul, you need `-u`:

```
% unichars -u '\p{InEthiopic}' | wc -l
     384    
% unichars -u '\p{InCJKUnifiedIdeographsExtensionA}' | wc -l
    6592
```

---

You can get other information, too:

```
 % unichars '\P{IsGreek}' '\p{InGreek}' 
 ʹ   884 0374 GREEK NUMERAL SIGN
 ;   894 037E GREEK QUESTION MARK
 ΅   901 0385 GREEK DIALYTIKA TONOS
 ·   903 0387 GREEK ANO TELEIA
 Ϣ   994 03E2 COPTIC CAPITAL LETTER SHEI
 ϣ   995 03E3 COPTIC SMALL LETTER SHEI
 Ϥ   996 03E4 COPTIC CAPITAL LETTER FEI
 ϥ   997 03E5 COPTIC SMALL LETTER FEI
 Ϧ   998 03E6 COPTIC CAPITAL LETTER KHEI
 ϧ   999 03E7 COPTIC SMALL LETTER KHEI
 Ϩ  1000 03E8 COPTIC CAPITAL LETTER HORI
 ϩ  1001 03E9 COPTIC SMALL LETTER HORI
 Ϫ  1002 03EA COPTIC CAPITAL LETTER GANGIA
 ϫ  1003 03EB COPTIC SMALL LETTER GANGIA
 Ϭ  1004 03EC COPTIC CAPITAL LETTER SHIMA
 ϭ  1005 03ED COPTIC SMALL LETTER SHIMA
 Ϯ  1006 03EE COPTIC CAPITAL LETTER DEI
 ϯ  1007 03EF COPTIC SMALL LETTER DEI

% unichars '\p{IsGreek}' '\P{InGreek}' | wc -l
 250
% unichars '\P{IsGreek}' '\p{InGreek}' | wc -l
  18

%  unichars '\p{In=1.1}' | wc -l
6362
%  unichars '\p{In=6.0}' | wc -l
15087
```

---

### *uniprops*

Here’s *uniprops*:

```
% uniprops -l | grep -c 'Block='
84

% uniprops digamma 450 %
U+03DC ‹Ϝ› \N{ GREEK LETTER DIGAMMA }:
    \w \pL \p{LC} \p{L_} \p{L&} \p{Lu}
    All Any Alnum Alpha Alphabetic Assigned Greek Is_Greek InGreek Cased Cased_Letter LC Changes_When_Casefolded CWCF
       Changes_When_Casemapped CWCM Changes_When_Lowercased CWL Changes_When_NFKC_Casefolded CWKCF Lu L Gr_Base
       Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Grek Greek_And_Coptic ID_Continue IDC ID_Start IDS Letter L_ Uppercase_Letter Print
       Upper Uppercase Word XID_Continue XIDC XID_Start XIDS XPosixAlnum XPosixAlpha XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixUpper
       XPosixWord
U+0450 ‹ѐ› \N{ CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IE WITH GRAVE }:
    \w \pL \p{LC} \p{L_} \p{L&} \p{Ll}
    All Any Alnum Alpha Alphabetic Assigned InCyrillic Cyrillic Is_Cyrillic Cased Cased_Letter LC Changes_When_Casemapped
       CWCM Changes_When_Titlecased CWT Changes_When_Uppercased CWU Cyrl Ll L Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase
       ID_Continue IDC ID_Start IDS Letter L_ Lowercase_Letter Lower Lowercase Print Word XID_Continue XIDC XID_Start XIDS
       XPosixAlnum XPosixAlpha XPosixGraph XPosixLower XPosixPrint XPosixWord
U+0025 ‹%› \N{ PERCENT SIGN }:
    \pP \p{Po}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Common Zyyy Po P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Other_Punctuation Punct Pat_Syn
       Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Punctuation XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
```

---

Or even all these:

```
% uniprops -vag 777
U+0777 ‹ݷ› \N{ ARABIC LETTER FARSI YEH WITH EXTENDED ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT FOUR BELOW }:
    \w \pL \p{L_} \p{Lo}
    \p{All} \p{Any} \p{Alnum} \p{Alpha} \p{Alphabetic} \p{Arab} \p{Arabic} \p{Assigned} \p{Is_Arabic} \p{InArabicSupplement} \p{L} \p{Lo} \p{Gr_Base} \p{Grapheme_Base} \p{Graph}
       \p{GrBase} \p{ID_Continue} \p{IDC} \p{ID_Start} \p{IDS} \p{Letter} \p{L_} \p{Other_Letter} \p{Print} \p{Word} \p{XID_Continue} \p{XIDC} \p{XID_Start} \p{XIDS} \p{XPosixAlnum}
       \p{XPosixAlpha} \p{XPosixGraph} \p{XPosixPrint} \p{XPosixWord}
    \p{Age:5.1} \p{Script=Arabic} \p{Bidi_Class:AL} \p{Bidi_Class=Arabic_Letter} \p{Bidi_Class:Arabic_Letter} \p{Bc=AL} \p{Block:Arabic_Supplement} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:0}
       \p{Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:Not_Reordered} \p{Ccc=NR} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:NR} \p{Decomposition_Type:None} \p{Dt=None}
       \p{East_Asian_Width=Neutral} \p{East_Asian_Width:Neutral} \p{General_Category:L} \p{General_Category=Letter} \p{General_Category:Letter} \p{Gc=L} \p{General_Category:Lo}
       \p{General_Category=Other_Letter} \p{General_Category:Other_Letter} \p{Gc=Lo} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:Other} \p{GCB=XX} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:XX}
       \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Other} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:NA} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:Not_Applicable} \p{Hst=NA} \p{Joining_Group:Yeh}
       \p{Jg=Yeh} \p{Joining_Type:D} \p{Joining_Type=Dual_Joining} \p{Joining_Type:Dual_Joining} \p{Jt=D} \p{Line_Break:AL} \p{Line_Break=Alphabetic} \p{Line_Break:Alphabetic}
       \p{Lb=AL} \p{Numeric_Type:None} \p{Nt=None} \p{Numeric_Value:NaN} \p{Nv=NaN} \p{Present_In:5.1} \p{In=5.1} \p{Present_In:5.2} \p{In=5.2} \p{Present_In:6.0} \p{In=6.0}
       \p{Script:Arab} \p{Script:Arabic} \p{Sc=Arab} \p{Sentence_Break:LE} \p{Sentence_Break=OLetter} \p{Sentence_Break:OLetter} \p{SB=LE} \p{Word_Break:ALetter} \p{WB=LE}
       \p{Word_Break:LE} \p{Word_Break=ALetter}
```

My [*uniprops*](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniprops) and [*unichars*](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars) should run anywhere running Perl version 5.10 or better.  There’s also a [*uninames*](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uninames) script that goes with them.

Answer (score 0):

There's a list available [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/index.htm) although it does not specific for which version of the standard it applies: